# JavaScript event that fires when all of the certain elements get display: none

Tags: javascript, html, events, event-handling

So, say, I have 5 **html elements** that are **hidden** via **class** that has a `display:none` property.
Then there's a **button** which removes that **class** on one of these elements with every **click** (5 clicks results into all 5 elements being visible).
And then all of these 5 elements have "their own **button**" that adds back this **class** with `display:none` when clicked.

Now, I want some other element to get invisible when all of these elements are invisible as well. And then, when at least one of them is visible (doesn't have `display:none`), I want this other element to be visible as well.

To complete the task, I was trying to use the **MutationObserver**.

```
let my_observer = new MutationObserver(function(mutations) {...}

elements_nodelist.forEach((my_element) => {
    observer.observe(my_element, {attributes: true, attributeFilter: ["class"]});
  })
```

But unfortunatelly, it reacts to just any class changes, it doesn't only watch the visibility state, or only this particular class changes. yes, I can get a `mutation.oldValue` information and get to the `element.classList`, but I can't figure out the way to use it to solve all this.

Comment: If your aim is to keep it **modular**, why not trigger custom events when the combined button hides an element or a button of that element hides, both handlers will emit `hidden` event which you can listen to and handle logic for *some other element*?

Comment: @MuhammadTalhaAkbar if I get this right, you mean to aim at the click events on these "hide" buttons and not on the elements' class changes events? That makes sense and that should work since all the class changes actually happen the same time you click a button. Adding Chema's advice about the .filter() method that should solve my current issue, thank you :) It's just that I further may add other buttons like "hide all the elements at once" and instead of adding this button's click event handler, I'd stick to the mutation observer that would require no changes in case of adding such a button.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check if all your hidden elements have the hidden class:

```
const myHiddenElements = [...document.querySelectorAll('.my-hidden-element')];

const isAnyVisible     = myHiddenElements.filter( elm => elm.classList.contains('hidden-class') ).length < myHiddenElements.length;

if( isAnyVisible ) {
    // Do what you want
}
```